# .htaccess not working in sub-folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, kohana, redirect

One of my clients ask to do some customization in his site. That site was developed in php with kohana framework. For new development, I copy and moved all the files to a sub-directory called **dev** including .htaccess. But the url redirection was not working. We need to give index.php on url to get every page. Kindly help me, what was the problem.

Comment: Accept your recent questions.

Comment: You should post the contents of the .htaccess file you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. In kohana framework, there is an option to set index controller.

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; //If empty it will call index.php
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; //I give value as index.php. The frame-work will add index.php in the url.
```

If any one find the correct way of redirection code. Please share it.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
RewriteBase /folder/
```

line to your .htaccess file before the actual Rewrite lines.

Answer (score 0):

Not enough details to answer conclusively. So here is your faux answer.

It's most likely that the webroot `RewriteRules` collect up **all** request paths (since the virtual paths in dev/ exist neither), so the `.htaccess` in a subdirectory below won't snatch.

The main RewriteRules can however be disabled for certain path patterns with an additional:

```
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !dev
```

(You might actually need a better differentiating factor, since the physical subdir name is unlikely to be used in the virtual request urls.)

Comment: I changed my development folder name as "semp". Yet redirection not working.